# Add class name to a html element by using html custom attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have some html elements with custom attributes

```
<div menuitemname="my-media" class="panel panel-default">
//some code here
</div>
```

i wonder if there is a way (js will be nice) to add the value, of custom attribute "menuitemname", to my element class. something like this

```
<div menuitemname="my-media" class="panel panel-default my-media">
//some code here
</div>
```

on my entire site

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('.panel').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).attr('menuitemname');
});
```

This will use the callback-function of `addClass()` to add the value of the attribute `menuitemname`

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rg9L1dbz/)**

---

Reference:

[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-function)

[attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName)

Answer (score 0):

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/JmHpC/106/

```
    $('[menuitemname="my-media"]').addClass('my-media');
```